# Is there a way to combine multiple time series from csv files so that values match dates

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I was wondering if there was an easier way to sort values by corresponding date from an excel file. The format is in .xts and is looking as following.

They all have overlapping data and the idea is to match each value by date and have the blanks as N/A

```py
9/10/2019   42,58   9/10/2019   50,69   15/10/2019  222,135
10/10/2019  42,935  10/10/2019  50,96   16/10/2019  222,285
11/10/2019  43,46   11/10/2019  51,32   17/10/2019  222,62
14/10/2019  43,165  14/10/2019  50,94   18/10/2019  222,62
15/10/2019  43,39   15/10/2019  51,08   21/10/2019  224,07
16/10/2019  43,26   16/10/2019  51
```

What I ideally am looking for instead of doing it manually in the excel file is having a time series like this:

```py
9/10/2019   42,58   50,69   50,69
10/10/2019  42,935  50,96   50,96
11/10/2019  43,46   51,32   51,32
14/10/2019  43,165  50,94   50,94
15/10/2019  43,39   51,08   51,08
16/10/2019  43,26   51      51
17/10/2019  43,37   51,28   51,28
18/10/2019  43,23   51,18   51,18
21/10/2019  43,2    51,34   51,34
```

I have tried the method cbind and trying to sort by date but it did not give the desired result.

Comment: Can you provide `dput` of your data? It seems that it is not properly read into R since decimals are separated by comma and not point and the date are also not formatted properly. Also can you add the code you tried?

Comment: Seems a `dplyr::full_join()` chain could help you (casual names of `data.frame`s and columns due you haven't give any of them). `library(dplyr);
df1 %>% full_join(df2, by ='V1') %>% full_join(df3, by ='V1')`>(`V1` is the date field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the data of excel file (time series) in data frames or list and then merge them together in an xts object:

`# Convert list to times series object, where each element of xlsx_list is a time series`

`A_xts = do.call(merge, xlsx_list)`